# Understanding DetectedBreak in google OCR full text annotations

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-vision, text-segmentation

I am trying to convert the full-text annotations of google vision OCR result to line level and word level which is in `Block`,`Paragraph`,`Word` and `Symbol` hierarchy.

However, when converting `symbols` to `word` text and `word` to `line` text, I need to understand the DetectedBreak property.

I went through [This documentation](http://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/grpc-google-cloud-vision-v1/0.1.5/apidocs/com/google/cloud/vision/v1/TextAnnotation.DetectedBreak.BreakType.html).But I did not understand few of the them.

Can somebody explain what do the following Breaks mean? I only understood `LINE_BREAK` and `SPACE`.

1. EOL_SURE_SPACE
2. HYPHEN
3. LINE_BREAK
4. SPACE
5. SURE_SPACE
6. UNKNOWN

Can they be replaced by either a newline char or space ?

Comment: The google cloud services have some of the laziest, poorly written docs I've seen out of any software company. The problem repeats itself over and over again with each new google cloud service I try and use. There must be something structurally wrong with Google that would enable this disease to spread from team to team, although I won't speculate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided has the most detailed explanation available of what each of these stands for. I suppose the best way to get a better understanding is to run ocr on different images and compare the response with what you see on the corresponding image. The following python script runs `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` on an image saved in GCS and prints all detected breaks except from the ones you have no trouble understanding (`LINE_BREAK` and `SPACE`), along with the word immediately preceding them to enable comparison.

```
import sys
import os
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import vision

def detect_breaks(gcs_image):

    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '/path/to/json'
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    feature = vision.types.Feature(
        type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)

    image_source = vision.types.ImageSource(
        image_uri=gcs_image)

    image = vision.types.Image(
        source=image_source)

    request = vision.types.AnnotateImageRequest(
        features=[feature], image=image)

    annotation = client.annotate_image(request).full_text_annotation

    breaks = vision.enums.TextAnnotation.DetectedBreak.BreakType
    word_text = ""
    for page in annotation.pages:
        for block in page.blocks:
            for paragraph in block.paragraphs:
                for word in paragraph.words:
                    for symbol in word.symbols:
                        word_text += symbol.text
                        if symbol.property.detected_break.type:
                            if symbol.property.detected_break.type == breaks.SPACE or symbol.property.detected_break.type == breaks.LINE_BREAK:
                                word_text = ""
                            else:
                                print word_text,symbol.property.detected_break
                                word_text = ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    detect_breaks(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: The problem is generating input for 6 types of `Break`. Except for `SPACE` and `LINE_BREAK`. And that's exactly is my question. What does those 6 `DETECTED_BREAK` mean?

Comment: Specifically `EOL_SURE_SPACE` and `HYPHEN` right now, Iam considering them as new lines

Comment: `EOL_SURE_SPACE` is basically a big eol and `HYPHEN` is that case where a word needs to be broken in the middle with a hyphen (`-`) at the end of a line. Check [this](https://fontshopblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/hyphen-4.png) for `HYPHEN` and [this](https://jeroen.github.io/images/testocr.png) for `EOL_SURE_SPACE`.

Comment: So to simply answer my question, is it safe to say `SPACE , SURE_SPACE` can be considered as `SPACE` and rest of them as `NEW_LINE`?

Comment: I guess that's up to you and your implementation. If you're willing to ignore the hyphen before the line ends or the fact that sure space is larger than a "standard" space then yes, it's safe.